# Можно ли применить sum DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, комбинаторика

Можно здесь вместо + применить sum ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from datetime import datetime

n_rows = 100
n_cols = 100
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])  


# Можно здесь вместо + применить sum ?
d = dict()
for x1, x2 in product(df1, df2):
    d['{0}_{1}'.format(x1,x2)] = df1[x1].values + df2[x2].values 
df3 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: А зачем? "+'" у вас здесь - row-wise операция. Метод pandas `sum` здесь не прикрутить, потому что это уже будет series-wise операция. А питоновский встроенный метод sum даст вам банальную сумму всех элементов всех серий - вы получите совсем не то, что нужно.

Comment: выскакивала ошибка, если я подставлял свои данные, но дело было в другом...вообщем все ок порешал, Спасибо за отклик @strawdog